# Why is changing a property from "init" to "set" a binary breaking change?

Tags: c#, properties, abi

I am coming back to C# after a long time and was trying to catch up using the book *[C# 10 in a Nutshell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-10-in/9781098121945/)*.

The author there mentions that changing a property's accessor from `init` to `set` or vice versa is a breaking change. I can understand how changing it from `set` to `init` can be a breaking change, but I just can’t understand why changing it the other way around would be a breaking change.

For example:

```
// Assembly 1
Test obj = new(){A = 20};

// Assembly 2
class Test
{
   public int A {get; init;} = 10;
}
```

This code in Assembly 1 should not be affected even if I change the `init` property accessor to `set`. Why then is this a breaking change?

Comment: Have you checked the IL for init vs set? I would assume they are different.

Comment: You might want to read the [Questions section of the proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/init.md#questions) "The downside of modreq is init becomes a part of the binary signature of the set accessor. Adding or removing init will break binary compatbility of the application."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because `init` accessors are compiled into a setter with a `modreq` declaration. The IL code for an int property `P` might look something like this (See on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAUEEsC2UECeAwgPYB2yMCcAxjCQsgDQwhYA2TAJiANQA+AAQBMARgCwAKEEBmAAQi5ROQG8pcjQvlYyMOelVyA5hBgBuOTqzm5AXym2gA==)):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname    
    instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) set_P (    
        int32 'value'   
    ) cil managed   
{   
    ...
}
```

Notice the token `modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit)`.

A normal setter does not generate this `modreq`.

On the caller's side, the call instruction must supply the `modreq` declaration as part of the signature of the thing to call, if and only if a `modreq` exists on that method. Therefore, the call to an `init` accessor would look like this:

```
callvirt instance void modreq([System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit) SomeClass::set_P(int32)
```

and not just

```
callvirt instance void SomeClass::set_P(int32)
```

If you changed to a setter, then all the calls to the `init` accessor must be changed to remove the `modreq`, or else it would not resolve the method correctly. Hence, this is a breaking change.

As for why `modreq` is used instead of a regular attribute to mark the property, see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init#breaking-changes) in the draft spec. To summarise, this is a trade-off between binary compatibility and "what would a compiler not aware of `init` accessors do". In the end they decided to sacrifice binary compatibility, so that a compiler that doesn't know about `init` *doesn't* allow code that sets the property.

Answer (score 11):

This is documented [in the design notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init#breaking-changes), specifically in the section titled "Breaking Changes".

> The emit strategy for init property accessors must choose between
> using attributes or modreqs when emitting during metadata. These have
> different trade offs that need to be considered.
>
> Annotating a property set accessor with a modreq declaration means CLI
> compliant compilers will ignore the accessor unless it understands the
> modreq. That means only compilers aware of init will read the member.
> Compilers unaware of init will ignore the set accessor and hence will
> not accidentally treat the property as read / write.
>
> The downside of modreq is init becomes a part of the binary signature
> of the set accessor. Adding or removing init will break binary
> compatbility of the application.

And the final decision was:

> Given there was also no significant support for removing init to be a
> binary compatible change it made the choice of using modreq straight
> forward.

So they used `modreq` in the implementation, with the result that replacing an `init` with `set` will be a binary breaking change.

There is more [discussion about `modreq` here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3376).

If you *really* want to know more about `modreq` then you can look for some details in [the CLI spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf).